# How to copy data from docker volume to host?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-volume

I have created a docker volume "hello" and it contains some data .

How can I copy the data to *host* ?

**First :**

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$ docker volume create --name hello
hello
```

**checking :**

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               hello
```

**volume "hello" inspect**

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$  docker volume inspect hello
[
    {
        "Name": "hello",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mountpoint": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/hello/_data"
    }
]
```

**How can i copy the data on the volume "hello" to host?**

> I tried :

```
kerydeMacBook-Pro:~ hu$  docker cp hello:/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/hello/_data /Users/hu/Desktop/12
Error response from daemon: no such id: hello
```

**It does not work as expected!**

Who can help me ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Docker does not provide an interface to access volumes directly but you can use a container that has the volume mounted. This may need a temporary container to be created:

```
CID=$(docker run -d -v hello:/hello busybox true)
```

Copy a directory from *volume* to *host*

```
docker cp $CID:/hello ./
```

To copy a directory from the *host* to *volume*

```
cd local_dir
docker cp . $CID:/hello/
```

Then clean up (if using a temporary container).

```
docker rm $CID
```

Comment: @Matt...yes,thanks,this question has resolved ! But ...Can i ask a deep question : How can i copy local data to docker volume **hello**, i try : `CID=$(docker run -d -v hello:/hello busybox true)`   then :  `docker cp $CID: ./data /hello`  ,,it has en error:`Error response from daemon: lstat /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/583e187 ..no such file or directory`   ..Can help me ?

Comment: Close. The container id is part of the source or destination, like `scp` uses a host name

Comment: @Matt...Sorry,i'm a newer to Docker , do not understand `The container id is part of the source or destination, like scp uses a host name` , Can you detail it ? and how to implement ? thanks !

Comment: No worries.. check the answer again. I edited it to show copying the other direction at the time of that comment, my scp comment was referring to those updates.

Comment: Why do we need a temporary container?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Docker doesn't provide another interface to access data from a `volume`

Comment: Worked for me thanks. You can also use a named container if you don't want to bother with IDs `docker run --name temp-name -d -v hello:/hello busybox true`, `docker cp temp-name:/hello ./`

Answer (score 12):

You do not need to run any additional container you can perform this task with the existing container.

Copy files from container to local path

```
docker cp CONTAINER:/var/logs/ /tmp/app_logs
```

Copy a local file into container

```
docker cp ./some_file CONTAINER:/work
```

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading the OS to a new version by side installing the new one and installing at the same time a SSD in addition to the old mech. HD, I've just transferred volumes from one system to another by
a simple file copy at the host level. The system is Linux Mint, and it should work the same for any *nix based box. Sorry by I don't know for Windows.

While running the new system:

- create the Docker volumes
- mount the disk of the old install
- locate there the volumes to be copied (under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`) based on the name
- copy (`copy -a -r`) their `_data` folder content to their counterpart
- enjoy

All these manipulations must be done as root of course.

After starting the Docker Compose stack on the new system, I've found all the data (including a PostgreSQL DB) there, exactly as they were in the old system.

Comment: Simple and more performant than the options relying on mounting another container (if you have sudo access, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner:

```
docker run --rm -v <volume>:/src -v $(pwd)/<dir>:/dest alpine sh -c 'cp -R /src/* /dest/'
```

Replace `<volume>` by the volume name & `<dir>` by a directory on the host (from the current location pwd)

This will:

- Run a tiny alpine container
- Mount the volume on `src`
- Mount the host's `<dir>` on `dest`
- Recursively copy `src` to `dest`
- Stop the container
- Delete the container